# Proximity Alert firing twice?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osmdroid

Receiver:

```
public class ProximityAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");

        Intent showDialog = new Intent(context, ShowMapDialog.class);
        showDialog.putExtra("id", id);
        showDialog.putExtra("Title", title);
        context.startActivity(showDialog);
    }

}
```

ShowMapDialog.java:

```
public class ShowMapDialog extends Activity {

PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
AlertDialog alertbox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Prefs sp = new Prefs();

    int lastplaceid = sp.getLastPlaceID(getApplicationContext());
    boolean nopopup = sp.getNoPopup(getApplicationContext());

    final int id = extras.getInt("id");
    String Title = extras.getString("Title");

    Log.d("id+title",id+"+"+Title);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "Place of Interest");

    if(id != lastplaceid && !nopopup) {
        wakeLock.acquire();

        sp.setLastPlaceID(getApplicationContext(), id);

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        int dot = 200;
        int dash = 500;
        int long_gap = 1000;
        long[] pattern = {0, dash, dot, dash, long_gap};
        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);

        alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMapDialog.this).create();
        alertbox.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialogTitle));
        alertbox.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialogShowPlaceText1)+Title+getString(R.string.dialogShowPlaceText2));
        alertbox.setButton(getString(R.string.dialogShowPlaceYes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent showPlace = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Showplace.class);
                showPlace.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(showPlace);
            }
        });
        alertbox.setButton2(getString(R.string.dialogShowPlaceNo), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    } else if(id != lastplaceid && nopopup){
        wakeLock.acquire();
        sp.setLastPlaceID(getApplicationContext(), id);
        Intent showPlace = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Showplace.class);
        showPlace.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(showPlace);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    wakeLock.release();
    alertbox.dismiss();
    finish();
}
```

}

Creating ProximityAlerts:

```
    private void setProximityAlert(String Title, double lat, double lon, float radius, final int id, int requestCode){
        // Expiration is x Minutes (x mins * 60secs * 1000milliSecs)
        long expiration = -1;

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        intent.putExtra("Title", Title);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        mlocManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void placeMarkersPoints(){
        this.dh = new DataHelper(ShowMap.this);
        List<Pontos> list = this.dh.selectAll();
        markerPlaces = new OverlayPlaces(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_places), mapView);
        for(Pontos p : list){
             markerPlaces.addPoint(new GeoPoint(p.getLat(),p.getLng()),p.getName().toString(),Integer.toString(p.getId()));
             setProximityAlert(p.getName().toString(), p.getLat(), p.getLng(), p.getRadius(), p.getId(), p.getId());
        }
        mapView.getOverlays().add(markerPlaces);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
```

I register the receiver on the onCreate like this:

```
    br = new ProximityAlert();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);
```

onPause:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    unregisterReceiver(br);
}
```

onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this);
    registerReceiver(br, mIntentFilter);
}
```

When I go through a second ProximityAlert, it does this code twice: `Log.d("id+title",id+"+"+Title);`

Any ideas? If needed, I can post more code :)

Comment: Why not just debug it?  Where are you actually stuck?

Comment: erm... I actually don't know what to debug to watch where it gets called...

Comment: @nitind take a look at the comment above please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my problem was with the BroadcastReceivers.

I was destroying them but not quite correctly, so sometimes they would double, or triple, or w/e.

Thanks but I solved it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You are registering the receiver every time the application resumes.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    registerReceiver(br, mIntentFilter); 
}
```

Consequently, every time each proximity alert is triggered (`PendingIntent`) multiple instances of the receiver will be fired (one for every time the activity is resumed).  Imagine that you have one caller and a universe of cloned receivers, who ALL answer back at the same time.

Creating `onResume` is fine, as long as the proximity alerts are removed / destroyed every time the application is paused `onPause()`.

Otherwise, create it once in your main / navigation activity.  In this case, the receiver will continue to fire even when the app is in background (which may [alarm app] or may not [display changes, for example] be the desired behavior).