# addProximityAlert and BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android

I am currently working on a map app that has points of interest built into it.
These points are supposed to be announced to the user by means of a proximity alert trigger.
Here is the addproximityAlert() code that I'm using

```
loc.addProximityAlert(lat, longe, radius, -1, PendingIntent.getActivity(
            c, 0, new Intent().putExtra(loc_name, loc_name), flag));
```

The idea is that once the alert fires an alert dialog pops up with a short blurb about the site with the option to either close the alert or get more info(uses WebView).

Thus far I have no run-time or compile-time errors but as I approach each site, nothing happens.

My theory on why nothing happens is that either;

1) I haven't used the PendingIntent correctly, or

2) I haven't set up the BroadcastReceiver correctly

Here is the XML code for the BroadcastRecevier,

```
<receiver android:name=".ProxyAlertReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="entering" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My current plan to fix this issue is to modify the PendingIntent to use a new Intent like this;

```
...new Intent(myContext, ProxyAlertReceiver.class)...
```

and see if I get any results.

Opinions and advice on my issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tested your BroadcastReceiver by creating a simple test Activity that broadcasts an Intent to see if you Intent Filter is setup correctly?

Comment: Yes, though I tried a couple of different kinds of broadcasts. I have tried TIME_TICK, sendBroadcast on a custom Intent that points at the BroadcastReceiver (though I don't know how to fully write up the xml intent-filter), and I have also tried a PendingIntent and that has failed too.  Nothing crashes, but nothing happens either.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)?

```
Intent locationReachedIntent = new Intent("entering");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234, 
    locationReachedIntent, 0);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(longitude, latitude, radius, -1, pendingIntent);
```

I have the above code working in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
Intent locationIntent = new Intent();
Bundle extras= new Bundle();
extras.putString("loc_name",loc_name);
locationIntent.putExtras(extras);
PendingIntent pendingIntent= new PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,locationIntent,0);
loc.addProximityAlert(lat, longe, radius, -1, pendingIntent, flag));
```

I assume your loc_name is a string. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a proximity alert depends on more than just calling the `addProximity` method on a `Location Manager`.

You must also:

1. Create a receiver class which will fire when alert is triggered and  will receive a status (entering or exiting) and the `action name`*;

   ```
   public class ProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public String TAG ="ProxReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       /* your code here - sample below */
       final String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
       final Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
       if (entering) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "LocationReminderReceiver entering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.v(TAG, "Poi entering");
       } else {
         Toast.makeText(context, "LocationReminderReceiver exiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.v(TAG, "Poi exiting");
       }
       Log.v(TAG,"Poi receive intent["+intent.toString()+"]");

       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       // debugging only
       int counterExtras = extras.size();
       if (extras != null) {
         for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
           Object value = extras.get(key);
           Log.d(TAG, "Prox Poi extra "+String.format("key[%s] value[%s] class[%s] count[%s]", key,
                   value.toString(), value.getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(counterExtras)));
         }
       } else {
         Log.v(TAG, "Prox Poi extra empty");
       }
    }
   }
   ```
2. Declare this receiver in your Manifest file;

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".ProximityReceiver" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="my" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. Register (associate your pending intents to) this receiver, adding proximity alert(s).  Only register your receiver ONCE in your code.  If one registers a receiver multiple times, it will fire once for every receiver instance (you reach a POI, which registers a pending intent called `"my"`. **

   ```
   // create proximity alert
   Intent locationIntent = new Intent("my");
   ProximityReceiver proximityReceiver = new ProximityReceiver();
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mapView.getContext(), <some identifying text>,
           locationIntent, 0);
   loc.addProximityAlert(lat, longe, radius, -1, PendingIntent.getActivity(
       c, 0, new Intent().putExtra(loc_name, loc_name), flag));

   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my");
   context.registerReceiver(proximityReceiver, filter);
   ```

Where `context` can be `this` if running in same activity.

Unless you want to keep on receiving alerts even when in background (or even terminated), you must implement removal and re-creation of proximity alerts in your `onPause` and `onResume` methods, like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10412677/1166727) (jump to the end of the question).

note * In this example, `"my"` will be the action name (see `Intent` declaration) for an action and will be passed along with the intent AND a bundle of extras containing, at least, the key `entering` (`LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING`) with boolean value, which gives you the state of the alert, if one is entering (1) or exiting (0) the proximity radius.

note ** If you have registered the receiver for `"my"` multiple times, it will fire multiple times for every proximity alert event that calls an intent named `"my"`.